Can't start sshd on Ubuntu server, sshd.service does not exist, despite clearly being installed
I rented a vps running Ubuntu on an ARM. I am able to SSH into the device without any problem. However, in order to reload the sshd config, I need to restart the sshd service through systemctl. For some reason, systemctl says it does not exist:
root@ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1:~# systemctl status sshd.service 
Unit sshd.service could not be found.
root@ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1:~# systemctl start sshd.service 
Failed to start sshd.service: Unit sshd.service not found.
root@ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1:~# systemctl enable sshd.service 
Failed to enable unit: Unit file sshd.service does not exist.

Yet, it exists:
root@ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1:~# systemctl -l --type service --all|grep ssh
  ssh.service                                           loaded    active   running OpenBSD Secure Shell server
● sshd-keygen.service                                   not-found inactive dead    sshd-keygen.service
● sshd.service                                          not-found inactive dead    sshd.service 

And is also installed:
root@ubuntu-4gb-nbg1-1:~# sudo apt-get install openssh-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
openssh-server is already the newest version (1:9.6p1-3ubuntu13.4).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.

I already tried removing it with purge and reinstalling it, as suggested in this answer, but unfortunately no luck. Problem persists.
Anyone have a clue what might be going wrong? It worked just fine two days ago.
EDIT: also note that sshd.service is being autocompleted when I TAB on systemctl...

IIRC sshd.service is just a symbolic link (/etc/systemd/system/sshd.service) alias to the real unit - which is named ssh.service

@steeldriver isn't ssh.service the client service?

AFAIK no - there is no client service (the ssh client is just a userland program). See answers to this related question Why not ssh.service but sshd.service?

@steeldriver looks like you are right. Damn, I was totally oblivious to this and feel dumb now...
Feel free to convert your comment into an answer, so I can accept it.
